# SSL Certificate for subdomain that points to different server (Amazon Web Services) - Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I am not into SSL at all, so bear with me please. I have no idea how to start to actually solve my problem.

**Current situation:**

- 1x Webserver with Webspace for a Website and it includes a Domain Administration, also to order SSL Certificates etc.
- 1x Different Webserver at Amazon Web Services with a PHP-based Software on it with Login etc.

  A Subdomain that I created in the Domain Administration is pointing via DNS to the IP of the AWS.

**What I need:**

I want an https Connection (SSL) for the Subdomain that is pointing to the AWS so that the connection/login is secure.

My question is what I have to do on the side where I have the Domain Administration and after that what I have to do on the side of the AWS.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options in hand,

- If you already have a SSL certificate purchased, you can include it inside the webserver (e.g; configure apache for SSL).

If you plan to use free SSL certificates from Amazon, you can use one of the following options after creating a SSL certificate in AWS Certificate Manager.

- Create a AWS CloudFront Distribution and attach the SSL certificate there while configuring an origin to forward traffic to the specific web server. However, you need to create the SSL certificate in North Virginia region and there won't be any upfront costs for CloudFront). CloudFront acts as a proxy and you can explicitly instruct to cache the static content reducing the load for web server and improving the performance.
- The other option is to create a Application Load Balancer (ALB) and attach the SSL certificate there ( Create the SSL certificate in the same region) while forwarding traffic to the web server. However, this will add a monthly reoccurring costs for the ALB.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

When I buy the SSL certificate at the Domain Administration, do I have to change the DNS Entry of the Subdomain in a normal Subdomain where I add the SSL Certificate.

After the Subdomain points to the IP of the AWS I just have to setup the apache for SSL. Did I get that right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. After purchasing the SSL certificate add it to Apache and point the DNS of the subdomain to the server IP. Also you might need to configure Apache to redirect from http to https.

Comment: Hello Ashan, I purchased an SSL certificate at the Domain Adminsitration its splitted up into CSR/KEY/KEY PHRASE (empty)/CRT/CA Certificate do you know a good step-by-step guide to get it running on my apache? I am not sure which one 100% fit my needs! Kind of confused. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello. Hope you have the certificate, key and intermediate. Check the following link https://www.sslshopper.com/apache-server-ssl-installation-instructions.html if the files are in a different format it requires to convert them using openssl

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, on AWS ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) procure a certificate for your subdomain and use AWS ELB to use the certificate and point to the AWS webserver. 
After this use the ELB IP in the DNS settings.

There are other options too like procuring the subdomain certificate and installing it on the webserver on AWS.